# Angular2 - reset the value of a select after user changes it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I have a `<select>` which the user can change. Initially it has a value and when the user changes it I must prompt her `"are you sure"?` and in case the answer is NO then change back the `<select>`'s selected value to the previous one. The `<select>` is bound to a collection of objects, not values.

The best I could come up with so far is this:

- in the html

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedObj" (ngModelChange)="onSelectedObjChanged($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let obj of availableObjs" [ngValue]="obj">{{whatever}}<option>
</select>
```

- in the code

```
onSelectedObjChanged(obj) {
  if (prompt answer is no) {
     let currentlySelectedObj = this.selectedObj;
     this.selectedObj = null;
     this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
     this.selectedObj = currentlySelectedObj;
     this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

This works, but is ugly. Why do I do it:

- there seems to be no way to cancel the selection changed event in the DOM
- when `onSelectedObjChanged` is called and the answer is "no", I need to somehow let angular know it has to refresh the binding target, i.e. the `<select>`...
- ...however I can't simply set `this.selectedObj = this.selectedObj` as the value doesn't change and there no change detected by angular; that's why I set it to `null` and back...
- ...however even that is not enough, I need to invoke `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` to notify angular of it

I'm sure there is a better and easier way to do this, it would be great if you could share some ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: `ngModel` shouldn't be written this way => `[(ngModel)]`?

Comment: It can, but then you're not notified of when the value changes so that you can prompt the user. `[(ngModel)]` expands to `[ngModel]=x (ngModelChange)=y`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 Dropdown revert to previously selected option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46357952/angular2-dropdown-revert-to-previously-selected-option)

Answer (score 11):

Here's how I did it:

HTML:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="option"
        #selectModel="ngModel"
        (ngModelChange)="optionChanged($event)">
    <option [ngValue]="null">PlaceHolder</option>
    <option *ngFor="let o of options" [ngValue]="o">...</option>
</select>
```

Component:

```
@ViewChild('selectModel') private selectModel: NgModel;

optionChanged($event) {
    //logic
    this.selectModel.reset(null);
}
```

Comment: this answer should be the accepted one. Works perfectly!

Comment: yep, adrian should set this answer as the accepted one

Answer (score 0):

I use `$event.target.value` instead of $event. I send `this.selectedObj = $event.target.value;` and `if failed` change `this.selectedObj = previousObject` I don't need any change detection.

Comment: I suspect you are using plain values and not a list o bound objects? Also, where do you keep `previousObject`?

Comment: I am using 

`<select (change)="myAction(thing._id, $event.target.value)" [(ngModel)]="selectedObject">

                <option *ngFor="let a of actionList" [value]="a">{{a}}</option>

              </select>` 
where actionList is a string Array.  I set a default this.selectedObject = this.previousObject from actionList and if the myAction() function returns false, I set this.selectedObject to that again.

Answer (score -1):

try `this.selectedObj = obj.target.value;` and than perform your condition.

Comment: I'm binding to a list of objects and using `ngValue`, so `obj.target.value` will be undefined.